# Nginx Virtual Server Blocks on Remote Server

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have NginX running on a server in my house, with IP 192.168.1.200. I would like to serve multiple website projects from it, by navigating to http://192.168.1.200/project1, http://192.168.1.200/project2 etc.

What server block configuration do I require to enable this? The only examples I can find relate to serving Nginx on your own machine and creating virtual server blocks with addresses like project1.local (which is then defined in the local machine's hosts file).

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to have been within my question, so I thought I would share it in case anyone else stumbles across the same issue.

The hosts file of the local machine needs to point an address like project1.local to the IP address of the server Nginx is hosted on.

the server name is also specified as project1.local in the Nginx virtual server block configuration.